# How to mske TeamCity trigger a build only for PRs to master branch?

Tags: git, github, teamcity, gated-checkin

I've configured build with the following branch specification:

`-:<default>
+:refs/pull/*/merge`

But such specification makes TC to trigger build for any PR, though I need this only for PRs to master.

Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding of what you wish to achieve is correct, then unfortunately it is not possible at the moment. There has been a [feature request for this in YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-43759) for quite some time.